# Prove by induction on a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

We have

$$ n \in R $$

And an arithmetic sequence of natural numbers different than 0 that the sum of all its members  = n
$$
a_1,a_2,...,a_k
$$

$$
a_1+a_2+...+a_k = n
$$
I need to prove **by induction** that for each n>0 there will be only 
$$2^{n-1}$$
groups like this.

For example:

For n=3 we have only 4 groups like this:

1,1,1 
1,2 
2,1 
3

How do I prove this by induction??

Thanks

Comment: You probably mean $a_1+\cdots+a_k=n$ where $k$ can take different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint (also see my comment):

Here $\mathbb N=\{1,2,\dots\}$

Tuple $\left\langle a_{1},\cdots,a_{k}\right\rangle \in\mathbb{N}^{k}$
with $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{k}=n$ induces the tuples $\left\langle 1,a_{1},\cdots,a_{k}\right\rangle \in\mathbb{N}^{k+1}$
and $\left\langle a_{1}+1,\cdots,a_{k}\right\rangle \in\mathbb{N}^{k}$.

This with $1+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{k}=n+1=\left(a_{1}+1\right)+\cdots+a_{k}$.

So stepping from $n$ to $n+1$ doubles the number of tuples.

---

**edit**:

Let $S_{n,k}:=\left\{ \left\langle a_{1},\cdots,a_{k}\right\rangle \in\mathbb{N}^{k}\mid a_{1}+\cdots+a_{k}=n\right\} $
and $S_{n}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}S_{n,k}$ .

To be shown (by induction)
is that $m_{n}=2^{n-1}$ where $m_{n}$ denotes the cardinality of
$S_{n}$.

It is evident that $m_{1}=1=2^{0}$.

From $m_{n}=2^{n-1}$ (induction hypothese) it will follow immediately that $m_{n+1}=2^{n}$
if we can prove that $m_{n+1}=2m_{n}$. So proving the last statement
will be enough.

Prescribe function $f:S_{n+1}\rightarrow S_{n}$ by $\left\langle a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{k}\right\rangle \mapsto\left\langle a_{1}-1,a_{2},\cdots,a_{k}\right\rangle $
if $a_{1}>1$ and $\left\langle 1,a_{2},\cdots,a_{k}\right\rangle \mapsto\left\langle a_{2},\cdots,a_{k}\right\rangle $
otherwise.

Then $f$ is a surjective function with $f^{-1}\left(\left\langle b_{1},\cdots,b_{k}\right\rangle \right)=\left\{ \left\langle 1,b_{1},\cdots,b_{k}\right\rangle ,\left\langle b_{1}+1,\cdots,b_{k}\right\rangle \right\} $
for every element $\left\langle b_{1},\cdots,b_{k}\right\rangle \in S_{n}$.

Then $\left\{ f^{-1}\left(\left\langle b_{1},\cdots,b_{k}\right\rangle \right)\mid\left\langle b_{1},\cdots,b_{k}\right\rangle \in S_{n}\right\} $
forms a partition of $S_{n+1}$. It contains $m_{n}$ sets and each
of these sets contains $2$ elements of $S_{n+1}$. This tells us
that $m_{n+1}=2m_{n}$.

Comment: I still can't see how you proved it, can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Is my comment correct? If so then repair your question.

Comment: Hi, you are correct, I'll edit it.

Comment: If $m_{n}$ denotes the number of groups for $n$ then do you understand
that (according to my hint) $m_{n+1}=2m_{n}$? Based on that you can
prove by induction that $m_{n}=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: I probably do not understand why.. can u please enlighten me? :)

Comment: I hope this helps.